# Does it make any difference when aligning a struct with 32 or 64 when its size is in between 32 and 64?

Tags: rust, memory, memory-management, alignment

```rust
#[repr(align(32))]
struct Data {
    array: [f64; 6],
}

fn main() {
    println!("size of Data: {}", std::mem::size_of::<Data>());
}
```

Without aligning keyword (`#[repr(align(32))]`), type `Data` consumes 48 bytes memory. But with the keyword, either `#[repr(align(32))]` or `#[repr(align(64))]`, it consume 64 bytes.

So, is there any difference when aligning it with 32 bytes or 64 bytes?

Comment: Aligning affects not only the size of data but also an address where it could be located. A struct aligned at 64 bytes can only start from address that is multiple of 64.

Comment: Is your question about the difference between `#[repr(align(32))]` and `#[repr(align(64))]`, or between `#[repr(align(anything))]` and no alignment instructions?

Comment: Are you asking what is alignment, or why is it causing a difference in the size?

Comment: I'm asking the difference between `#[repr(align(32))]` and `#[repr(align(64))]`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the alignment (the memory addresses that are valid for `Data`) differs, and it makes a difference for example in [structures containing a `Data`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c46a6f205603f1d13c656d6e40a520a8):

```rust
#[repr(align(32))]
struct Data32 {
    array: [f64; 6],
}

#[repr(C)]
struct DD32 {
    offset: u8,
    data: Data32,
}

#[repr(align(64))]
struct Data64 {
    array: [f64; 6],
}

#[repr(C)]
struct DD64 {
    offset: u8,
    data: Data64,
}

fn main() {
    println!("size of Data32: {}", std::mem::size_of::<Data32>());
    println!("size of DD32: {}", std::mem::size_of::<DD32>());
    println!("size of Data64: {}", std::mem::size_of::<Data64>());
    println!("size of DD64: {}", std::mem::size_of::<DD64>());
}
```

Output:

```
size of Data32: 64
size of DD32: 96
size of Data64: 64
size of DD64: 128
```

And everywhere else where alignment matters.

Comment: A relevant location where alignment tends to matter a lot is vector instructions, which are a lot less forgiving about alignment than scalar. I think AVX512 prefers (but does not require) 64b alignment.

Comment: Note that `#[repr(align)]` does not guarantees an alignement, it guarantees only it will be _at least_ X bytes.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of reasoning, let's suppose we have an array of `Data`.
Each element of this array must have an address conforming to the specified alignment.

The unique member `[f64; 6]` is 48 bytes long, thus a `Data` is at least 48 bytes long.
We try to determine how many bytes are missing between each chunk of 48 bytes in this hypothetical array, so that each `Data` is correctly aligned.

With `align(32)`, 32 - (48 % 32) = 16.
If a first `Data` is aligned on 32, we need to skip 16 more bytes for the next `Data` to be also aligned on 32.
Then the size of `Data` must be 48 + 16 = 64.

With `align(64)`, 64 - (48 % 64) = 16.
If a first `Data` is aligned on 64, we need to skip 16 more bytes for the next `Data` to be also aligned on 64.
Then the size of `Data` must be 48 + 16 = 64

Without `align(...)` the natural alignment is probably 8 because of the `f64` in the member, (48 % 8) = 0.
If a first `Data` is aligned on 8, we don't need to skip any more bytes for the next `Data` to be also aligned on 8.
Then the size of `Data` is simply 48.

Comment: Note that this is not _necessary_, we could have size of 48 and only insert padding in case of an array (but Rust will never do that).

Comment: Also note that alignment of `f64` (as well as all other primitives) is not guaranteed, the layout algorithm is not guaranteed, `#[repr(align)]` causing this aligment is also not guaranteed (basically, almost nothing is guaranteed).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah? I thought `sizeof([T; N]) == N × sizeof(T)`, especially when it comes to `malloc()` under the hood. Anyway, you are right, my answer is not focused on the conformance to the reference but more on explaining the numerical values observed in the OP. I agree also about the natural alignment of `f64` (`double`) which I have already seen as 8 or 4 depending on the platform (on mine it's 8 right now).

Comment: Yes, sure, but it doesn't _have_ to be defined this way.